# ECSでcronのような定期的な処理をしたい

Tags: aws, laravel, aws-lambda, cron

LaravelのアプリケーションをECS(Fargate)でデプロイしたいのですが、定期的に外部APIを叩いてRDSを更新するような機能を実装したいと思っています。

ECSの場合、cronではなくScheduled TaskやLambdaなどを使うような記事を見たのですが方法がいくつかあるのでしたらそれぞれのメリットなど教えていただけると幸いです。